# Google Map API Key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am new to android development. 
I would like to know is the Google Map API v1 key had been deprecated since 3rd Dec 2012?
If it is so will the Google Map API v2 key compatible with android ver. 2.3.3 (Gingerbread)?
Because I am developing android application on Gingerbread ver.
Will the v1 key usable in v2 key?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know is the Google Map API v1 key had been deprecated since 3rd Dec 2012?

Your Maps V1 key should work indefinitely. You will be unable to obtain new Maps V1 keys as of 3 March 2013.

> If it is so will the Google Map API v2 key compatible with android ver. 2.3.3 (Gingerbread)?

Maps V2 will work on many Android 2.3.3 devices, those that support OpenGL ES 2.0 and have the Google Play Services app (obtained through the Play Store).

> Will the v1 key usable in v2 key?

The Maps V1 key will only work with Maps V1. The Maps V2 key will only work with Maps V2.